# How to define initial state $\rvert \Psi(0) \rangle \equiv \rvert 1, -1 \rangle \otimes \rvert 0 \rangle_{\text{cav}} $ of a system in QuTiP?

Tags: quantum-state, programming, qutip

Say, we have a $\require{mhchem}\ce{^87Rb}$ atom having an electric dipole transition on the $D_{1}$ line and we have two hyperfine ground states, one on $F = 1$ and one on $F = 2$ level. So, we take two pair of states $|F=2, m=-2\rangle$ and $ |F=1, m = -1\rangle$ as the ground state. The details on this can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6063). I need to find time evolution of the probability of being in the initial state  $$|\Psi(0)\rangle \equiv | 1, -1 \rangle \otimes | 0 \rangle_{\text{cav}}.$$

I don't understand how to define the initial state in QuTiP. I have gone through the paper 'QuTiP: An open-source Python framework for the dynamics of open quantum systems' by J.R. Johansson, P.D. Nation, Franco Nori. I have found few examples such as cavity in its ground state which  coupled to a qubit in a balanced superposition of its ground and excited state $$|\Psi(0)\rangle=\left(|0\rangle_{c}|0\rangle_{q}+|0\rangle_{c}|1\rangle_{q}\right) / \sqrt{2}$$ and atom in excited state $$|\Psi(0)\rangle=\operatorname{tensor}(\text { fock }(\mathrm{N}, 0), \text { fock }(2,1)).$$ But I am still not able to understand how to define the initial state $|\Psi(0)\rangle \equiv | 1, -1 \rangle \otimes | 0 \rangle_{\text{cav}} $ in QuTiP.

Can anyone please help me understand this?

Comment: do you mean how you define an initial state in general? or how to define that specific state? What are the dimensions of the spaces here?

Comment: @glS, I want to understand how to define the given specific state $|\Psi(0)\rangle \equiv | 1, -1 \rangle \otimes | 0 \rangle_{\text{cav}}$. The dimension of the space is related to the number of cavity fock states and in this case it is $N =2$.

Comment: yea but what that means depends on the context. That state can be for example `qutip.tensor(qutip.basis(2, 0), qutip.basis(2, 1), qutip.basis(5, 0))`, or something completely different, depending on how you model the different spaces and the conventions you use